# creating separate connection file in class form

Tags: php

I've created separate connection file now I want to change it in class form.
Here my code is,

```
<?php 
$servername="localhost";
$username="dd";
$password="*******";
$database="Db";

class Connection
{
    function connect()
    { 
        $con = mysql_connect($servername,$database,$username,$password) || die("Error connecting to database");
        mysql_select_db("dd_KrishnaDb") or die ("database selection problem");  


    }
}
?>
```

now when I include this file in my index.php file it's not establishing a connection in index.php file.

```
<?php
include_once ('Connection.php');
     $db = new Connection();
  ?>
```

I got  Access denied for user ''@'localhost' error.So please tell me what is wrong in my code.

Comment: Learn about variable scopes.

Comment: mysql_ out dated try to use myqli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your `Connection.php` file

```
class Connection
{
    public function __construct(){
        $this->servername   = 'localhost';
        $this->username     = 'root';
        $this->password     = 'xxxxxxxxx';
        $this->database     = 'myDB';
    }
    public function connect()
    {
        $conn =  mysqli_connect($this->servername, $this->username, $this->password,$this->database);
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like someone pointed out here already; `mysql` functions are going away.... and this means, it's time for an upgrade... preferably to `PDO`. Here's what your class might look like (assuming you are going the `PDO` route).

```
    <?php
        /**
         * FILENAME: Connection.php
         */

        // IT IS PREFERABLE TO HAVE A SEPARATE FILE FOR THIS AND THEN INCLUDE IT
        // DATABASE CONNECTION CONFIGURATION:
        defined("HOST")    or define("HOST",   "localhost");  // YOUR HOSTNAME
        defined("DBASE")   or define("DBASE",  "Db");         // YOUR DB NAME
        defined("USER")    or define("USER",   "dd");         // YOUR USERNAME
        defined("PASS")    or define("PASS",   "root");       // YOUR PASSWORD

        class Connection {

            /***
             * @var \PDO
             */
            private static $dbHandle;

            public static function connect(){
                if(!isset(self::$dbHandle)){
                    self::$dbHandle = self::getInstance();
                }
                return self::$dbHandle;
            }

            private static function getInstance(){
                try {
                    self::$dbHandle = new \PDO('mysql:host='.HOST.';dbname='. DBASE,USER,PASS);
                    self::$dbHandle->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                    return self::$dbHandle;
                }catch(\PDOException $e){
                    throw new \Exception($e->getMessage());
                }
            }
        }

    ?>
```

And, now in your Script, you can include the Connection.php File and get your Database Connection handle like this:

```
    <?php
        include_once ('Connection.php');
        $db     = Connection::connect(); // GET THE DB CONNECTION HANDLE

        var_dump($db);  // DUMPS THE PDO OBJECT...
    ?>
```